# Does there exist a quantities which can be absolutely measured in physics?

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602029/236734), I had an argument with some users about how inexact differentials turn exact under constrained paths.

So, the discussion began on this point: **For a given path**, could we call unconstrained' inexact differential to be a state function?

One argument is that we need to define a specific reference for each kind of path we take, but I think that's irrelevant to the fact of it being an exact differential under a constrained path because once the constraint is said, we can write an arbitrary constant for that path. And, even then when we go to calculate the actual 'integral' to calculate work over two states under the constraint, the constant disappears anyway.

More precisely, it is correct to say that the inexact differential under constraints becomes an exact state function only for that particular constraint path?

Comment: Unitless quantities should be absolutely measurable, e.g. width of atomic transition lines, relative to some other lines etc.

Comment: But to measure 'width' , you need to define length @Cryo

Comment: Eager to see an answer

Comment: How about integer values, like the number of nucleons in a nucleus?